# How to sort values as numbers in NatTable?

Tags: java, nattable

My problem is, that data values are sorted as strings, although I used `DefaultDoubleDisplayConverter`. I registered converter to cell labels, not to column header label. My code:

```
public class NatTableFactory {
  private NatTable createTable(Composite parent, List<TableLine> tLines, String[][] propertyNames,
      PropertyToLabels[] propToLabels, TableParams params, TextMatcherEditor<TableLine>editor, boolean openableParts) {
    
    BodyLayerStack bodyLayerStack =
        new BodyLayerStack(
                tLines,
                tLines.get(0).getLength(),
                params.getColumnIndicesForRowHeaders());
    
    ...

    SortHeaderLayer<TableLine> sortHeaderLayer =
        new SortHeaderLayer<TableLine>(
            columnHeaderLayer,
            new GlazedListsSortModel<TableLine>(
                bodyLayerStack.getSortedList(),
                getSortingColumnPropAccessor(propertyNames[0]),
                configRegistry,
                columnHeaderDataLayer));
 
    ...
    
    composite.addConfiguration(NatTableLayerConfigurations.getCompoositeLayerConfiguration());
    
    NatTable natTable = new NatTable(parent, composite, false);
    
    if( params.getAutoFitColWidthIndices().size() > 0 )
      registerAutoResizeColCmdHandler(natTable, composite, bodyLayerStack, params.getAutoFitColWidthIndices());
    
    setNatTableContentTooltip(natTable);
    
    natTable.setConfigRegistry(configRegistry);
   
    natTable.addConfiguration(new SingleClickSortConfiguration());
    
    natTable.addConfiguration(new DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration());

    setNatTableContextMenu(natTable, openableParts);
    
    natTable.addConfiguration(NatTableLayerConfigurations.getNatTableConfiguration());        
    
    //natTable.addConfiguration(NatTableLayerConfigurations.getCustomConvertConfiguration(bodyDataLayer));
    
    natTable.configure();

    ...

    NatTableContentProvider.addNatTableData(natTable, bodyLayerStack.getSelectionLayer(), bodyLayerStack.getBodyDataProvider());
    
    return natTable;
  }
}
```

then:

```
public class NatTableLayerConfigurations
{
  ...

  public static AbstractRegistryConfiguration getNatTableConfiguration()
  {
    return new AbstractRegistryConfiguration()
    {

      @Override
      public void configureRegistry(IConfigRegistry configRegistry)
      {
        ...    
        Style cellAlignStyle = new Style();
        cellAlignStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT, HorizontalAlignmentEnum.RIGHT);
        configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, cellAlignStyle, DisplayMode.NORMAL, NatTableFactory.DataTypeNumberLabel);
        //
        configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
            CellConfigAttributes.DISPLAY_CONVERTER,
            new DefaultDoubleDisplayConverter(), DisplayMode.NORMAL,
            NatTableFactory.DataTypeNumberLabel);
        System.out.println("configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute CellConfigAttributes.DISPLAY_CONVERTER");
        
        ...
      }
    };
  }
}
```

and:

```
public class BodyLayerStack extends AbstractLayerTransform
{
  ...    
  public BodyLayerStack(List<TableLine> values, int columnCount, Integer[] columnIndicesForRowHeaders)
  {
    EventList<TableLine> eventList = GlazedLists.eventList(values);
    TransformedList<TableLine, TableLine> rowObjectsGlazedList = GlazedLists.threadSafeList(eventList);

    sortedList = new SortedList<>(rowObjectsGlazedList, null);
    // wrap the SortedList with the FilterList
    filterList = new FilterList<>(sortedList);
    
    bodyDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<TableLine>(filterList, getColumnAccessor(columnCount));
    bodyDataLayer = new DataLayer(bodyDataProvider);

    IConfigLabelAccumulator cellLabelAccumulator = new IConfigLabelAccumulator() {
      
      @Override
      public void accumulateConfigLabels(LabelStack configLabels, int columnPosition, int rowPosition) {
        int columnIndex = bodyDataLayer.getColumnIndexByPosition(columnPosition);
        int rowIndex = bodyDataLayer.getRowIndexByPosition(rowPosition);
        if( isRowHeader(columnIndicesForRowHeaders, columnIndex) ) {
          configLabels.addLabel(NatTableFactory.RowHeaderLabel);
        } else {
          configLabels.addLabel(filterList.get(rowIndex).getObjectTypeByColumn(columnIndex));
          
          // NatTableLayerConfigurations.getNatTableConfiguration();
        }
      }
    };
    bodyDataLayer.setConfigLabelAccumulator(cellLabelAccumulator);
    
    GlazedListsEventLayer<TableLine> glazedListsEventLayer = new GlazedListsEventLayer<>(bodyDataLayer, filterList);
    
    ...    
  }
}
```

I checked various examples, but I can not see, what do I miss. And how can I check, if data in cells were converted correctly? Thanks for some hint.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are missing the configuration of the sort comparator.

This is explained in our documentation: https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=sorting

The following examples show the usage:

- [SortableGridExample](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/examples/_130_Sorting/SortableGridExample.java)
- [GroupByCustomTypesExample](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_600_GlazedLists/_605_GroupBy/_6052_GroupByCustomTypesExample.java)

Comment: Hi @Dirk, I wanted to use default comparator, It should compare Double data type as well. In that case I though, I do not need to register it. In examples above are custom comparators used, so I assume, I need custom comparator

Comment: Then you need to register your custom default comparator for SortConfigAttributes.SORT_COMPARATOR without region and label specification. Then you get the object and need to do the type check there. I don't know a way how you could access the cell labels from within a Comparator.

Comment: I registered custom comparator in `NatTableLayerConfigurations`, but without success. My code: 
   ` // Register custom comparator
          configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(SortConfigAttributes.SORT_COMPARATOR,
                    getCustomComparator(),
                    DisplayMode.NORMAL,
                    NatTableFactory.DataTypeNumberLabel);`

Maybe I need to register `cellLabelAccumulator`  to the column header layer as well?

Comment: If you want to register it as a default comparator, then why do you register it for a label? Is that label set in the column header where the click happens? In case it should be the replacement for the default comparator of NatTable, remove the DisplayMode and label parameter.

Comment: Hi @Dirk, I have got labels only in cells, not in column headers. I needed to register one custom comparator for "Number" label and another custom comparator for "String" label. All cells in table have one of those two labels. If I try register comparator to whole column, then it works. My problem is, that in one column can be both types of labels

Comment: You can only have one comparator per column. So you have to deal with that.